# Symfony 3: How can I inject a service dynamically depending on some runtime variable

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

let's say I have the following interface/concrete classes:

```
interface EmailFormatter

class CvEmailFormatter implements EmailFormatter
class RegistrationEmailFormatter implements EmailFormatter
class LostPasswordEmailFormatter implements EmailFormatter
```

I then have a custom 'mailer' service that's called from my controller actions in order to send an email.

What options do I have for injecting the correct implementation of EmailFormatter to my mailer service depending on the type of email being sent?

Comment: Typical solution would be to inject a EmailFormatterFactory and then do something like:  $formatter = $emailFormatterFactory->create('registration');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a service that picks the right formatter during runtime, either some kind of factory or if your formatters have dependencies maybe a service were you inject the formatters from the container. Something like this:

```
class MailController extends AbstractController
{
    private $mailer;
    private $mailFormatterSelector;

    public function __construct(...) { ... }

    public function someAction()
    {
        // Do stuff ...

        if (...some condition) {
            $formatter = $this->mailFormatterSelector->getRegisterMailFormatter();
        } else {
            $formatter = $this->mailFormatterSelector->getLostPasswordEmailFormatter();
        }
        $mailer->sendEmail($formatter);

        // Do more stuff ...
    }
}

class MailFormatterSelector()
{
    private $registrationFormatter;

    public function __construct(EmailFormatter $registrationFormatter, ...)
    {
        $this->registrationFormatter = $registrationFormatter;
        ...
    }

    public function getRegisterMailFormatter(): EmailFormatter
    {
        return $this->registrationFormatter;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Alternatively if you have to pass the formatters into your mailer during construction, you can also create multiple, differently set up instances with different aliases and then inject them as needed into the services and controllers like this:

```
# config/services.yaml
mailer1:
    class: MyMailler
    arguments:
        $formatter: '@formatter1'
mailer2:
    class: MyMailler
    arguments:
        $formatter: '@formatter2'

MyMailController:
    arguments:
        $mailer: '@mailer2'
```

In your controller or action you can then pass in mailer1, mailer2, ... (maybe with nicer names) via.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The only problem I see with the first option is that injecting the formatters into MailFormatterSelector in the first solution would get clunky if there were 10 different formatters for example.

With the second solution, I don't know which formatter I need until I'm in the controller action so it cannot be defined statically.

Comment: Yes, if you have many formatters you might want to use an `addFormatter()` method and then use service tags and CompilerPasses to assign them or if you use a recent Symfony version [use the Service Locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_locators.html)

Comment: Yeah thanks that's bang on, I'm using an older version of Symfony, this is a good example it seems: https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/service_container/tags.html

Comment: Yes, like this.

Comment: There is a Symfony ServiceLocator service which is the best to use for this case. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html